jmeter json extractor removes double quotes""
output in jmeter json extractor is xyz@manuf.com & i want it as "xyz@manuf.com"
I am trying to fetch a key by jmeter json extractor, but it removes double quote.
I want to use that value in other api
I try by using regular expression after it
eg. get all data using $.data[0]
After it add Regular Expression Extractor using your JMeter variable as email and created a new variable using the following regex
email":"([^"]+)"
Template $1$ and Match No. 1
But the value with quotes not displayed using ${email_g0}

How about adding the quotation marks manually where required, i.e. instead of ${foo} in the next request use "${foo}"?

If you want to add quotation marks around the JMeter Variable value you can do this using JSR223 PostProcessor and the following Groovy code:
vars.put('foo', '"' + vars.get('foo') + '"')

Replace foo with the JMeter Variable name produced by the JSON Extractor and it will add quotation marks and update the variable value
There is also __strReplace() function in Custom JMeter Functions plugin which can be used for the same.
${__strReplace(${foo},(.*),"$1,foo)}

